# What is a super-recursive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I ran across this term for the first time today and the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-recursive_algorithm) entry for it doesn't really tell me much:

> In computability theory, super-recursive algorithms are a
>   generalization of ordinary algorithms that are more powerful, that is,
>   compute more than Turing machines.

Comment: Hey once you get an answer, you can edit the tag too!

Comment: Is that tag really useful?

Comment: @MarcioB Since non-computable algorithms aren't realizable in software more or less by definition, probably not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Recursive here does not refer to an algorithm that uses itself as a subroutine; rather, it refers to the class of recursive functions, which are those which can be computed by a Turing machine. A super-recursive function, then, would be a function which a Turing machine is not powerful enough to compute, requiring a more powerful computing model.

For example, the halting problem would require a super-recursive algorithm, since it is not solvable using an ordinary Turing machine.

Comment: I see, but are there any known examples of super-recursive algorithms (obviously there would be no actual implementation) or do we just know the types of problems which would require them?

Comment: We just know the types; our ordinary language for describing algorithms assumes a Turing machine as the computation model, so there won't be an example in the sense you would like. This might actually be a very good question for cs.stackexchange.com.